# Word ending in "-ine" for rat-like

Tags: single-word-requests

There are several words ending in "-ine" that can be used to make comparisons to animals. These include equine (resembling a horse), canine (resembling a dog), vulpine (resembling a fox) and porcine (resembling a pig).

Is there a word with the same ending that means resembling a rat?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96118/discussion-on-question-by-aliden-word-ending-in-ine-for-rat-like).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, there is ***[murine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/murine)*** which appears to be used mainly in [academic papers](https://scholar.google.it/scholar?hl=it&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=murine&btnG=):

> of or relating to a murid genus (Mus) or its subfamily (Murinae) which includes the common household rats and mice.

(M-W)

Comment: Now I want to know how the Murine Ear Wax Removal drops got its name.

Comment: @Barmar - from the chemical formula “***mur***inate of barber***ine***” when the brand was created, initially for eye remedy drops. https://www.google.com/amp/s/reginajeffers.blog/2017/04/06/do-you-know-the-history-of-murine-eye-drops/amp/

Comment: And yet the advertising slogan for Murine eye drops isn't "It gets the rat out!"

Comment: You can find lots more at http://phrontistery.info/genitive.html

Comment: Dang, been holding on to this one for a long time.  Someone finally asks and I miss my chance!